# How to vertically center align text with background image

Tags: html, css

I want to center align text vertically in the list, but it is currently not doing it correctly. Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

```css
.lista .lista1 {
    background-image: url(http://evenimente.academiasuccesului.ro/wp-content/themes/responsive/images/1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 70px;
    padding-left: 80px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 68px;
}
.lista .lista2 {
    background-image: url(http://evenimente.academiasuccesului.ro/wp-content/themes/responsive/images/2.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 70px;
    color: black;
    padding-left: 80px;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 68px;
}
.lista .lista3 {
    background-image: url(http://evenimente.academiasuccesului.ro/wp-content/themes/responsive/images/3.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 70px;
    padding-left: 80px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 68px;
}
.lista .lista4 {
    background-image: url(http://cristianfertea.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/4.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 70px;
    padding-left: 80px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 68px;
}
.lista {
    list-style: none;
}
.lista li {
    margin: 10px 63px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="lista">
    <li class="lista1"><h5 style="/* padding-top: 25px; */">Schimbarea perspectivei in management</h5></li>
    <li class="lista2"><h5 style="padding-top: 28px;">Solutii pentru un management eficient</h5></li>
    <li class="lista3"><h5 style="padding-top: 27px;">Abordari inedite si eficiente in management si leadership</h5><p>&nbsp;</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just remove comment from `<h5 style="/* padding-top: 25px; */">`  and give `padding-top: 25px !important;`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to add this in CSS:**

```
#theme-page h5 {
color: #393836;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 70px;
text-transform: uppercase;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: did you added in the same class? Its working.. thats why showed screenshot

Comment: what you did is ok for resolutions only large but mobile isn`t aligned to the center.
I wanted something that would be aligned with the center for all resolutions.
As you did and I've managed to align the text to large resolutions utlizand "padding: top: X value"

Comment: for mobile are you resizing the list image using media query, if so then change line height value according to image height..

Answer (score 0):

Just remove those h5, it is not appropriate in this context.

```css
.lista .lista1 {
        background-image: url(http://evenimente.academiasuccesului.ro/wp-content/themes/responsive/images/1.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        line-height: 70px;
        padding-left: 80px;
       color:black;
font-size:18px;
height:68px;
    }


.lista .lista2 {
        background-image: url(http://evenimente.academiasuccesului.ro/wp-content/themes/responsive/images/2.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        line-height: 70px;
 color:black;      
  padding-left: 80px;
font-size:18px;
height:68px;
    }


.lista .lista3 {
        background-image: url(http://evenimente.academiasuccesului.ro/wp-content/themes/responsive/images/3.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        line-height: 70px;
        padding-left: 80px;
 color:black;    
font-size:18px;
height:68px;
}

.lista .lista4 {
        background-image: url(http://cristianfertea.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/4.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        line-height: 70px;
        padding-left: 80px;
 color:black;    
font-size:18px;
height:68px;
}

    .lista {

       list-style: none;   
    }  

.lista li{
 position: relative;
 margin: 10px 63px;
}
```

```html
  <ul class="lista">
    <li class="lista1">Schimbarea perspectivei in management</li>
    <li class="lista2">Solutii pentru un management eficient</li>
    <li class="lista3">Abordari inedite si eficiente in management si leadership</li>
</ul>
```